# How matrix value is assigned in fortan

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran77

Here is my simple program for 2 by 2 matrix

```
program matrix

INTEGER :: A(2,2)
integer::i,j

do i = 1,2

      write(*,*) A(i,1),A(i,2)


end do
     end program
```

and when I run and compile I get the output of

```
15866218  1869135244
   11         -2
```

I want to know why this four no. came and how...I was expecting output like

```
A(1,2)   A(1,2)
A(2,1)  A(2,2)
```

But it has value instead. Any help?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I wish to know why this value was listed as output..why not any other like any other numbers other then this. can you help me to understand logic here why 11 or -2 or first two no ..not any others?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark so this are random values then? if I want to assign like A(1,1) =1 ,A(1,2) =0 , A(2,1) =0 and A(2,2) =1 or an identity matrix as output ..what should I change in my code..can you help me?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thanks I did it by ...but If i want to create say an identity matrix of 5 by 5 or more....is there any neat way to create identity matrix..then to assign individual matrix element value with 0 and 1.

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark okay thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized the values in your matrix. You have to tell the compiler to put some kind of value into the matrix, or you just get whatever number was in those memory addresses before your program ran.